# 401 unauthorized for PUT/PATCH/DELETE with Devise and Rails-api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, routes

I have a RAILS API that integrates Devise and Doorkeeper. My POST request to registrations#create works but PUT/PATCH/DELETE results in "401 unauthorized" error. I suspect it might be some issue with authentication on Devise but that's where I'm stuck. Perhaps I am missing how to deal with current_user or skip_before_filters? I have tried a number of things like adding

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!
```

Thank you!

routes.rb

```
require 'api_constraints'

Rails.application.routes.draw do

    use_doorkeeper
    devise_for :users, only: [:registrations, :passwords, :confirmations], controllers: {registrations: "api/registrations"}, defaults: { format: :json }

    namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json }, constraints: { subdomain: 'api' }, path: '/' do
        scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiConstraints.new(version: 1, default: true) do
            get 'users/me', to: 'users#me'
        end
    end
end
```

rake routes

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                  Controller#Action
                          GET    /oauth/authorize/:code(.:format)             doorkeeper/authorizations#show
      oauth_authorization GET    /oauth/authorize(.:format)                   doorkeeper/authorizations#new
                          POST   /oauth/authorize(.:format)                   doorkeeper/authorizations#create
                          DELETE /oauth/authorize(.:format)                   doorkeeper/authorizations#destroy
              oauth_token POST   /oauth/token(.:format)                       doorkeeper/tokens#create
             oauth_revoke POST   /oauth/revoke(.:format)                      doorkeeper/tokens#revoke
       oauth_applications GET    /oauth/applications(.:format)                doorkeeper/applications#index
                          POST   /oauth/applications(.:format)                doorkeeper/applications#create
    new_oauth_application GET    /oauth/applications/new(.:format)            doorkeeper/applications#new
   edit_oauth_application GET    /oauth/applications/:id/edit(.:format)       doorkeeper/applications#edit
        oauth_application GET    /oauth/applications/:id(.:format)            doorkeeper/applications#show
                          PATCH  /oauth/applications/:id(.:format)            doorkeeper/applications#update
                          PUT    /oauth/applications/:id(.:format)            doorkeeper/applications#update
                          DELETE /oauth/applications/:id(.:format)            doorkeeper/applications#destroy
oauth_authorized_applications GET    /oauth/authorized_applications(.:format)     doorkeeper/authorized_applications#index
oauth_authorized_application DELETE /oauth/authorized_applications/:id(.:format) doorkeeper/authorized_applications#destroy
         oauth_token_info GET    /oauth/token/info(.:format)                  doorkeeper/token_info#show
            user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#create {:format=>:json}
        new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)                devise/passwords#new {:format=>:json}
       edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)               devise/passwords#edit {:format=>:json}
                          PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#update {:format=>:json}
                          PUT    /users/password(.:format)                    devise/passwords#update {:format=>:json}
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                      api/registrations#cancel {:format=>:json}
        user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                             api/registrations#create {:format=>:json}
    new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                     api/registrations#new {:format=>:json}
   edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                        api/registrations#edit {:format=>:json}
                          PATCH  /users(.:format)                             api/registrations#update {:format=>:json}
                          PUT    /users(.:format)                             api/registrations#update {:format=>:json}
                          DELETE /users(.:format)                             api/registrations#destroy {:format=>:json}
        user_confirmation POST   /users/confirmation(.:format)                devise/confirmations#create {:format=>:json}
    new_user_confirmation GET    /users/confirmation/new(.:format)            devise/confirmations#new {:format=>:json}
                          GET    /users/confirmation(.:format)                devise/confirmations#show {:format=>:json}
             api_users_me GET    /users/me(.:format)                          api/v1/users#me {:format=>:json, :subdomain=>"api
```

registrations_controller.rb (that overrides Devise)

```
include ActionController::ImplicitRender

class Api::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  clear_respond_to
  respond_to :json
  respond_to :html, only: []
  respond_to :xml, only: []

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  before_filter :not_allowed, only: [:new, :edit, :cancel]

  def not_allowed
    render json: {error: "Method Not Allowed"}, status: 405
  end

  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit([
      :email,
      :password,
      :password_confirmation,
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
    ])
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit([
      :email,
      :first_name,
      :last_name,
      :password,
      :password_confirmation,
      :current_password
    ])
  end
end
```

Application.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  respond_to :json

  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == 'OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Token'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'

      render text: '', content_type: 'text/plain'
    end
  end

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Token'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end

  def current_resource_owner
    User.find(doorkeeper_token.resource_owner_id) if doorkeeper_token
  end

end
```

Comment: `skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token` is to disable CSRF protection on controlle. and `skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have selectively override `Devise::RegistrationsController` methods, which are `:new, :edit, :cancel`.

Rest methods are not defined in your class therefore they will be served by `Devise::RegistrationsController`.

If you open devise [source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb), you will see :

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, only: [:new, :create, :cancel]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

As you can see that `:create` action does not require authentication therefore you don't see 401 for `POST` request as it matches to `create` action.

`PUT/PATCH` matches to `update` action which requires authentication, similarly `DELETE` matches to 'destroy' action which also requires authentication therefore you are getting this 401 error.

To solve this issue, Add [doorkeeper authorize](https://github.com/doorkeeper-gem/doorkeeper#protecting-resources-with-oauth-aka-your-api-endpoint) for protected action after overriding actions in your `RegistrationsController`.

Comment: Thanks @Anial Maurya, I had to put `skip_before_filter :authentication_scope!`  in my custom registration controller and add `doorkeeper_authorize: api`. In addition I also had to override `current_user` and `update_resource` to get the full CRUD operations to work.